# How to create multiple login views using Zend Framework?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm new to ZF and need to create multiple login views for each of my 3 user types, employees, employers and admins.  Should I use the indexcontroller to serve up the login for the employees and create separate controller classes to handle the employer and admin login pages?  How might I utilize JQuery to direct my employer and admin users to the correct login page from the index view?

Thanks much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can give you 2 options.

1. Modules

   Split your Application into logical segments called modules, for those 3 groups each group will receive its own Module.
   Each module mimics the well known standard "Application" structure:

   - module

     - Controllers
     - Models
     - etc
2. ACL

   http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html

   You check which type of user is currently logged and decid via "if()" statements which view should be rendered.
   Custom view rendering is done as described by "Lobo":
   via

   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('view-name');

---

If you don't have any user session data, I mean, if you absolutely do not know of which kind the user visiting your page is you simply have to serve 3 links to either a different module or different controller or to one and the same controller but passing the user type as param.

Examples:

Link to module: `/modulename/controllername/actionname/`

Link to certain controller: `/emplyeecontroller/login`

Link to general controller handling different params: `/logincontroller/login/type/emplyee`

---

There are many possible solutions to achieve your desired aim.
You have to decide which one fits the most into your project.

Comment: Thanks much for these options. I'm going to use the first approach. Can you confirm that Zend ACL should not be used with the first approach?

Comment: If your users are not already logged in you don't have any data which indicate their type, so you can use ACL if you have session data available you can use these data to perform a role check with ACL against them.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that this is a bit to open ended to answer in a good way, but I'll try to fill in the blanks with my imagination and give you an answer. I don't use JQuery so I can't give you an answer there unfortunately.

If this is just to handle login I would guess that the logic is more or less the same (and even if it isn't the logic should be in models anyway), and you just want to change the visual appearance, so then you could use the code

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender('view-name');
```

This code will render the view called /application/views/scripts/*controller*/*view-name*.phtml by default. Thus you can get whatever variable you use to distinguish the different users and give them the right view.

If there's more differences than just the visual I would probably use different actions within a loginController or something like that. 
Then I would use standard indexAction (and thus the view index.phtml as default) for the normal employees, and on that page show some kind of text like "Not an employee? Go to the employers login instead". Employers are then directed to login/employer or something like that which by default will call the employerAction and use the employer view. And then you do something similar with the admin login. the controller will then look something like this

```
<?php
class LoginController 
{

public function indexAction()
{
    /*Do login stuff here*/

}

public function employerAction()
{
    /*Do login stuff here*/

}

public function adminAction()
{
    /*Do login stuff here*/

}

}
```

Lastly, if there are major differences between how the different users interact with your page, you might consider looking into modules.

You can find all this information at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/manual.html